# How can I add events to Android default calendar on button click?

Tags: android, events, calendar, cursor, android-contentresolver

```
protected void addToCalendar()
    {
        final ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "displayName" }, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
            String[] calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        final int[] calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
        Log.i("Cal Names Length", "Length of Cals:"+calNames.length);
        Log.i("Names of calendar:", "Cal names:"+calNames.toString());
        for (int i=0; i<calNames.length; i++)
        {
            calIds [i] = cursor.getInt(0);
            calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();
            Log.i("Calendar", "Cal_id:"+calIds[0]);
            Log.i("Calendar", "Cal_Name:"+calNames[0]);
        }
        cursor.close();

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        if(calIds.length > 0)
        {
            Log.i("in if condition", "Of calIds.length");
            Calendar cal =  Calendar.getInstance(); 
            Date birth_date = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < final_list.size(); i++)
            {
                    obj = final_list.get(i);
                    String dateFromDB = obj.getmBirthday();

                    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    try 
                    {
                         birth_date = parser.parse(dateFromDB);
                    } 

                    catch (java.text.ParseException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                 // event insert
                    int cal_id = calIds[0];
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put("calendar_id", cal_id);
                    Log.i("Calendar", "Cal_ID:"+cal_id);
                    values.put("title", obj.getmName());
                    Log.i("Title", "Title:"+obj.getmName());

                    values.put("dtstart", birth_date.getTime());

                    values.put("dtend",  birth_date.getTime() + 1800*1000);

                    values.put("duration",  1800*1000 );
                    values.put("description", "Birthday Reminder");
                    values.put("allDay", 1);
                    values.put("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
                    values.put("visibility", 0);
                    values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
                    cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), values);


            }

        }

    }
```

I have used this method on button click. When I click on the button ArrayList of Events should be added to Default calendar of Android Device. But here in this code, I am unable to see the event that is added to Calendar. And I even think that entry is not being added to calendar.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use, and it works in my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", startDate.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("endTime", endDate.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("title", title);
activty.startActivity(intent);
```

The event is added to android calendar, but it's not checked to see if the same event is already there (possible duplicate of the event)

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to add ArrayList of Events to calendar? I should create that many instances of Calendar?

Comment: I think you will find the answer you're looking for here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688837/insert-multiple-events-in-android-calendar?rq=1

Comment: I have gone through this but I cant see the event added to My Calendar(default calendar of android), even after adding cal_id as 1.

Comment: Do you catch any exception? Have you tried removing one of the field from your "values" to see if nothing's wrong with your data?

Comment: Yes I have tried. The values entering are printed correctly on log.

Comment: What I meant was, try to add only the minimum fields like I did in my example : beginTime, endTime and Title. Check if the event is added, if it is add one element after the other and see which one is blocking. If it's not, then the error is elsewhere.

Comment: Even then its not getting added to calendar. Can you please help me to add array of Entries to Calendar? Thanks.