# Struggling to set multiple events/reminders in android calendar

Tags: android, calendar

Please Help..!

I'm trying to set multiple events/reminders in app. for that I have written the following code (Please see the code below) there is no error in my code, code is getting run successfully but after running my code when I open my Calendar to view the Event, I found that there is no event set..!  I have referred answers suggested on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688837/insert-multiple-events-in-android-calendar)  but still not working.. My Code to set reminder is

```
private void addReminder(int statrYear, int startMonth, int startDay, int startHour, int startMinut, String title)
{               
    long calID = 3;
    long startMillis = 0; 
    long endMillis = 0;     
    Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    //  Sets the year, month, day of the month, hour of day, and minute fields.
    beginTime.set(statrYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinut);  //  set(int year, int month, int day, int hourOfDay, int minute).

    startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(statrYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour+1, startMinut);
    endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
    values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
    values.put(Events.TITLE, "Multiple Event Test");
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "My Calendar Test");
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Israel/tel-aviv");
    Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

}
```

I have called this method 3 times (to set 3 reminders at a time) on button click event as-- (please see the following code)

```
multiEventbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multi_event);

    multiEventbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {               
            int statrYear=2013, startMonth=9, startDay=21, startHour=9, startMinut=0;
            String strRemindarTitle="Title";
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {                   
                strRemindarTitle=strRemindarTitle+""+i+1;
                addReminder(statrYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinut, strRemindarTitle);

                startDay++;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event "+(i+1)+"  Date= "+startDay+"/"+startMonth+"/"+statrYear, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "strReturnData= "+strReturnData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

Please Help...! Thanks..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this its working fine. Make sure the values and calendar_id is proper:

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
            long startMillis = 0; 
            long endMillis = 0;     
            Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            beginTime.set(2000, 1, i, 7, 30);
            startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
            Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            endTime.set(2000, 1, i, 8, 45);
            endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
            values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
            values.put(Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
            values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
            values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
            values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
            Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

            // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
            long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            }
```